# Is this a good way to transfer PWM signals from microcontroller to output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, buffer

I want to have PWM signals on my board output connectors and do not want to connect those connectors directly to the microcontroller PWM pins.

I drew a schematic and have placed a voltage follower with an LM358 *to add some isolation and protection*.

I've read somewhere that using a voltage follower has some advantages, like adding some isolating between input and output, because of its different input and output impedance. Is this a correct schematic?

[image]

edited: I've read about voltage follower [here](https://www.elprocus.com/what-is-voltage-follower-working-its-applications/)

And the advantages of it is listed as below:

*It gives a gain of power as well as current.

*Less output impedance of the circuit uses the output.

*This operational amplifier uses zero current from the input.

*It avoids loading effects.

*It does not enhance or diminish the input signal’s amplitude.

*High-frequency noise cannot be filtered out.

*It has less output impedance.

*It has a high input impedance.

*Unity transmission gain.

Comment: "*do not want to connect those connectors directly to the microcontroller PWM pin*" For what reason?

Comment: @DKNguyen Hi, to add some isolation and protection

Comment: OP amps are probably fare less robust than a MCU port these days.

Comment: _"to add some isolation"_ Opamps does not offer isolaion.

Comment: Just add some series resistors then.

Answer (score 5):

> to add some isolation and protection

Offers no isolation at all, and protection: we don't know your microcontroller, but usually microcontroller outputs are more robust than Opamp outputs.

So, this offers nothing you want!

If you need to actually isolate, then a sufficiently fast optoisolator to isolate both the switched voltage and two different grounds would probably be the way to go. You might need to use the optocoupler to control a switching transistor (for example, a log-level n-Channel MOSFET).

The question is really: What kind of isolation do you need? What are you protecting against what? Writing that down often leads to very surprising results!

Comment: thank you Marcus for your time. I had made a mistake for sure.. I made an edit to my question and added some advantages of the voltage follower, dose it worth to use?

Comment: you haven't answered the three questions I posted at the end of my answer, so how should I know? You've just copied some meaningless properties of voltage followers, which don't address your use case, because you haven't defined what you need.

Comment: Sorry Marcus. yes I'm confused a little bit in what I actually want. 
my microcontroller is STM32H750VBT, and I want to transfer the pwm signal from microcontroller to the output connector and at the same I want to protect the microcontroller pwm pin from voltage surges and user errors(for example connecting an output voltage to the connector by mistakes)

Comment: yeah, that's still not describing the things that would happen, or what you do with the PWM. That's important. So, what is the thing attached to the external connector? What would a "user errors" actually do? What is "an output voltage"?

Comment: I do not know the application of the pwm ouput in my board, cause I've just told to  also provide a PWM output (beside other peripherals). so to clarify this I should ask the manager

Comment: yes, that would be called "getting the specifications before beginning to design something"!

Answer (score 4):

Using an op-amp would work if the output you want is PWM which is already low pass filtered to analog voltage.

The op-amp output will not go near supply rails unless you select a better op-amp. So output does not go to ground or supply voltage and has it limited slew rate.

If you really want to buffer the digital logic signal, use a digital logic buffer instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can find op-amp drivers, but they can be expensive.

You should explore some digital drivers like 74LVC1G126. Use this one as an example to find one that you like. These are more robust. Search Digikey or Mouser for digital logic drivers.

Cheers

Comment: thank you for your time and helping me today. I will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

> to add some isolation and protection

Just add some series resistors then. That limits the current for the internal ESD diodes on the MCU pins and protects against higher power. If you're paranoid you can add on external clamp diodes so you don't need to rely on the internal ones. Look at ESD and transient protection schemes.

An op-amp is not going to tolerate that kind of thing any better than an MCU pin.

Comment: thank you @DKNguyen for your reply and time, I will check it out!